# Add & Remove class using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to add "dots" that scroll through on my webpage just for devices.

However the JQ isn't working - does anyone have any ideas on how i can fix this -My code below.
Thanks

HTML:

```
 <span id="thumbs_wrapper">
    <ul class="thumbs">
        <li class="sliderindicator"></li>
        <li class="sliderindicator"></li>
        <li class="sliderindicator"></li>
        <li class="sliderindicator"></li>
        <li class="sliderindicator"></li>
    </ul>
    </span>
```

CSS:

```
span#thumbs_wrapper ul.thumbs li.sliderindicator {
background-color: #cccccc;
border-radius: 4px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
display: inline-block;
height: 8px;
margin-left: 3px;
margin-right: 3px;
width: 8px;}

span#thumbs_wrapper ul.thumbs li.sliderindicator.active { background-color: #069;}
```

JQ:

```
$('#thumbs_wrapper li.sliderindicator').slide(function() {
$('#thumbs_wrapper li.sliderindicator').removeClass('active');    
$(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Please provide jsFiddle

Comment: @zerkms jQuery I imagine

Comment: @andrew: I see - perhaps OP saved resource of "u", "e", "r", "y" keys on their keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

You have this tag missing `);`  u just used `}` so u got console error.  Proper closing =>  `});`

There is no `slideDown` Method use slideDown/Up. See [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) and [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/)

```
$('#thumbs_wrapper li.sliderindicator').slideDown(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active').addClass('active');
});
```

Used Chaining [**Details**](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp).

Comment: Hi you can just use $(this).removeClass( "active" ); right?

Comment: @AntoKing yes cascading can be done , Check updated answer. But it should be Upto some level only else The code becomes difficult to understant